# Best way to go about switching views using MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, monogame

I'm working on a game where I am using a UI framework which works with XAML and MVVM. I have managed to get my framework hooked up and I am able to switch between views. Right now I am using data-templates along with the ContentControl to switch views, I am also using a state-like pattern to switch and I was wondering if this is a good approach to use? I am having a small problem with my views, the way I have things set up currenly I have my MainWindow.xaml which contains a data-template to my other xaml files. The problem is the views just get added to the MainWindow.xaml and I'm wondering if there is a way to hide the previous view/content so it looks as if I'm switching between windows/views rather than just adding to them. Here is a screenshot to illustrate what I currently have.[Image of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw6vx.png). My xaml files are very simple and just contain a button for now, here are my xaml files:
`

```
MainWindow.xaml
<Grid
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PsalmsOfEia"
    xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:PsalmsOfEia.UI.Menus.ViewModels"
    xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PsalmsOfEia.UI.Menus.Views">


    <Grid.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:MainViewModel />
    </Grid.DataContext>

        <Grid.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:LoginViewModel}">
                <views:LoginView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Grid.Resources>

         <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
            <StackPanel>
            <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/> 
            <Button Content="Login" Command="{Binding ChangeCommand}"/>
        </DockPanel>


   </Grid>

LoginView.xaml

   <UserControl x:Class="PsalmsOfEia.UI.Menus.Views.LoginView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:PsalmsOfEia"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800"
             xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:PsalmsOfEia.UI.Menus.ViewModels"
             xmlns:views="clr-namespace:PsalmsOfEia.UI.Menus.Views">

        <UserControl.DataContext>
            <viewmodels:LoginViewModel />
        </UserControl.DataContext>

        <UserControl.Resources>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewmodels:CreateCharacterViewModel}">
                <views:CreateCharacterView/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </UserControl.Resources>
    <StackPanel>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedViewModel}"/>
        <Button Content="Click Here" Command="{Binding LoginCommand}"/>

    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

`

Could anyone tell me if there is a better way of switching views as well as how to hide the content of the previous views (since at the moment everything is being added to the main window).

Thanks

-Joshmond

Comment: Your setup looks mostly reasonable; they shouldn't be "adding" together with a content control like that, it should swap out.

Answer (score 0):

Not really sure what you're looking for but I use a `TabControl`

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="Tab1">
        <local:UserControl1/>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Tab2">
        <local:UserControl2/>
    </TabItem>

    <TabItem Header="Tab3">
        <local:UserControl3/>
    </TabItem>        
</TabControl>
```

I try to minimise the amount of XAML in one file, so I create a `UserControl`  and add them into the main view.

Answer (score 0):

Im using stackpanel and usercontrol.

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackpanel1"  Grid.Row="0"  />
    <StackPanel x:Name="myStackpanel2"  Grid.Row="1"  />
    <Button x:Name="myButton" Width="200" Height="30" Grid.Row="2" Click="myButton_Click" Content="Click Me SP1" />
    <Button x:Name="myButton2" Width="200" Height="30" Grid.Row="3" Click="myButton2_Click" Content="Click Me2 SP2" />
</Grid>
```

Code

```
private int i,j = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void myButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        i++;
        if (i % 2 == 0)
        {
            myStackpanel1.Children.Clear();
            myStackpanel1.Children.Add(new UserControl1());
        }
        else
        {
            myStackpanel1.Children.Clear();
            myStackpanel1.Children.Add(new UserControl2());
        }

    }

    private void myButton2_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        j++;
        if (j % 2 == 0)
        {
            myStackpanel2.Children.Clear();
            myStackpanel2.Children.Add(new UserControl2());
        }
        else
        {
            myStackpanel2.Children.Clear();
            myStackpanel2.Children.Add(new UserControl1());
        }
    }
```